# Does the temporary of a smart pointer have a reference count, or if so, does it insrement its reference count?

Tags: c++, smart-pointers, temporary

I have a question while reading "Section 12.1" of "C++ Primer 5th". It can be described as followed:

```cpp
auto p = std::shared_ptr<int>(new int(42));
std::cout << p.use_count() << std::endl;
```

The output will be "1" which means there is only one `shared_ptr` refers to the object. But the "counter" associated with a `shared_ptr` will be incremented when used as the right-hand operand of an assignment(Page 452, Line 4 of C++ Primer 5th). As a result, if temporary `std::shared_ptr<int>(new int(42))` has a counter, it will increment its counter to 2 after used as the right-hand operand of an assignment. I don't know the details of the implementation of smart pointers, does the temporary of a smart pointer have a reference count? If so, does it inscrement its reference count?

Comment: A temporary object is an object just like any other object and has exactly the same behaviour as if you created then destructed a non-temporary object

Comment: There are however no temporaries in your example. It is the same as doing `std::shared_ptr<int> p(new int(42));`

Comment: There is no assignment in your code, `Object x = 5;` still calls the constructor, not the assignment operator.

Comment: even if there was a temporary and even if it was assignment, the temporary would be destroyed at the end of the expression. In the next line the use_count can only be 1 because there is only 1 smart pointer

Comment: Why do you worry? Performance? Are you afraid of accidentally writing code that results in a smart pointer with a corrupted ref count?

Comment: Even if there were a temporary, how many references to the shared `int` do you think there would be *after* the temporary's destruction? (The counter is not associated with the `shared_ptr` but with the shared object.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for all the comments above. I've understood this problem.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the temporary `shared_ptr` has a reference count. However, in your example there is no temporary, this line `auto p = std::shared_ptr<int>(new int(42));` just calls a constructor. If you want to observe reference count being increased and decreased by creation of temporary copy, you can do:

```
std::shared_ptr<int> p1{new int(1)};
std::cout << p1.use_count() << std::endl;  // prints 1
std::cout << std::shared_ptr<int>(p1).use_count() << std::endl;  // prints 2, because you made a temporary copy of your original ptr
std::cout << p1.use_count() << std::endl;  // prints 1 again, temporary was destroyed
```